# pip install errors out for "automate" package

Tags: python

I was trying to install a library using PIP but encountered this error used the following command (python -m pip install automate)

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-GrBLn4/pyinotify/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-GrBLn4/pyinotify/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-oAHcRE
         cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-GrBLn4/pyinotify/
    Complete output (1 lines):
    inotify is not available on macosx-10.15-x86_64
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: I assume you are on MAC. It says inotify is not available in that OS. Did you google on that subject?

Answer (score 0):

> inotify is not available on macosx-10.15-x86_64

Seems like your OS is not supported, because a dependency of the library you are trying to install is not available.